# Locking does not lock my variable as I want it to

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to increment a variable using multithreading. However when I run the code, the counter stays at 1. When I remove the second sleep, it works as normal (increments to 5), however I can't seem to figure out how to properly lock the variable.

I already tried locking the variable before tmp is created as well as other lock methods (with lock, try-finalize,...).

```
class Casino:
    euro = 0


class PlayingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, the_casino, playerno=1):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.playerno = playerno
        self.the_casino = the_casino

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        tmp = self.the_casino.euro
        time.sleep(1)
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.the_casino.euro = tmp + 1
        self.lock.release()


casino = Casino()
lt = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    pt = PlayingThread(casino, i)
    pt.start()
    lt.append(pt)

for t in lt:
    t.join()

print("We earned a lot of money! Sum=", casino.euro)
```

The expected output would be "We earned ... Sum=5" but it is "... Sum=1"

Comment: When you say "locking the variable", what variable do you mean? If you mean `euro`, what makes you think your threads lock `euro`? If you mean some other variable, what variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two bugs. The first is the one mentioned in Solomon Slow's answer. You don't hold the lock during the entire read-modify-write operation. That can be fixed, as you suggested, by moving the lock acquire up.

But you have another problem -- no lock protects `euro`. Each thread locks *itself*, permitting each thread to acquire the lock on itself and still do the read-modify-write concurrently.

To fix that, there needs to be a specific lock that protects `euro` and all operations on it must be done under the protection of that single lock. I added a lock to `Casino` to do that.

Here's the fixed code:

```
import threading
import time

class Casino:
    euro = 0
    lock = threading.Lock();


class PlayingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, the_casino, playerno=1):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.playerno = playerno
        self.the_casino = the_casino

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.the_casino.lock.acquire()
        tmp = self.the_casino.euro
        time.sleep(1)
        self.the_casino.euro = tmp + 1
        self.the_casino.lock.release()


casino = Casino()
lt = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    pt = PlayingThread(casino, i)
    pt.start()
    lt.append(pt)

for t in lt:
    t.join()

print("We earned a lot of money! Sum=", casino.euro)
```

I think you might be missing something fundamental about how locks work. A lock has no idea what it locks and doesn't prevent anything other than two threads holding the same lock at the same time. You want to ensure that no thread can read `euro` in-between some other thread reading `euro`, incrementing the read value, and writing back to it. The way to do that is to ensure that every thread that might interact with `euro` in any way holds a single, specific lock.

When we say that some particular lock protects some particular piece of data, what we mean is that no thread attempts to access or modify that particular piece of data without holding that particular lock. Obviously, this requires that the code be carefully constructed to comply with this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your threads all *read* the variable before they lock it

```
    tmp = self.the_casino.euro
```

The second sleep ensures that all of the threads have time to see `self.the_casino.euro` equal to zero before any of them changes it.

Then, after they wake up, each of them sets it to `tmp + 1` (i.e., they each set it to `1`).

---

If you want to get `5`, then you need to make reading and updating the variable a single atomic operation.  You do that by putting both the read and the update in the same critical section.

Comment: Yes, that's why I tried putting the lock before the read. But that didn't help. Does lock not prevent reading?

Comment: @wieli99 The `Lock` object has no knowledge of the `Casino` object.  Locking a lock only prevents other threads from locking the same `Lock` at the same time.  It doesn't protect any variables.  If you want the variables to be protected, then it's up to you to ensure that your threads only access them while holding the lock.

Comment: sorry if I'm being stupid here but shouldn't 'acquire -> read -> write -> release' fix it then?

Comment: I can't comment on code that I haven't seen. My answer explains why I am not surprised that the program you showed us prints `...Sum=1`.

Comment: the code would remain the same, I would just pull the lock.acquire() up two lines - after sleep(2) - and I don't understand why that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
class Casino:
euro = 0


class PlayingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, the_casino, playerno=1):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.playerno = playerno
        self.the_casino = the_casino

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.lock.acquire()
            self.the_casino.euro += 1
        finally:
            self.lock.release()


casino = Casino()
lt = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    pt = PlayingThread(casino, i)
    pt.start()
    lt.append(pt)

for t in lt:
    t.join()

print("We earned a lot of money! Sum=", casino.euro)
```

The problem is that you are not actually incrementing the casino.euro, it's always 0 and being assigned to tmp.